# How can I join these rows together with commas as a column in my select?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG(SELECT department FROM additionaldepartments WHERE employee = e.EMPID, ',') AS additional_departments,
    r.actionId,
    e.EMPID AS `id`,
    CONCAT(e.FIRSTNAME, ' ', e.LASTNAME) AS `name`,
    b.ID AS `branch_id`,
    b.NAME AS `branch_name`,
    b.EMAIL AS `branch_email`,
    d.departmentDescription AS `primary_department`,
    j.JobType AS `job_role`
FROM
    actionplanresponsibleemployees r
        JOIN
    employee e ON e.EMPID = r.employeeId
        JOIN
    branch b ON b.ID = e.BRANCHID
        LEFT JOIN
    hremploymentdepartments d ON d.departmentPK = e.DepartmentFK
        JOIN
    hrjobtype j ON j.JobTypeID = e.JOBTYPE
```

The first line of the select will not work, I know this, but I'm just trying to demonstrate what it is I want from this query,

What I'm trying to achieve, is to have another column in my select called `additional_departments` which would be the `department` field from my `additionaldepartments` table, joined together in a string separated with commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(department) 
     FROM additionaldepartments 
     WHERE employee = e.EMPID) AS additional_departments,
    r.actionId,
    ........................
```